# How to delete all keys from object which are not defined in other siblings objects from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Given below is an array :

```
var array = [ {"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":3, "c":1}, {"a":9, "b":2}, {"a":7, "b":2}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":6}];
```

I need to delete all those objects from array which do not contain `"c"` key. For Example :

```
{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":9, "b":2}, {"a":7, "b":2}
```

are those objects from array which do not contain `"c"` key.

Please, do not use `"delete"` operator of javascript because, it is apart from requirement in my project.

**The expected output** : `var array =  [{"a":3, "b":3, "c":1}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":6}];`

Comment: Your question title has nothing to do with the question body. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a filter:

```
x = x.filter(o => 'c' in o);
```

```js
var x = [ {"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":3, "c":1}, {"a":9, "b":2}, {"a":7, "b":2}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":6} ];

x = x.filter(o => 'c' in o);

console.log(x);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you do not have ES6 support:

```
x = x.filter(function(o) {
    return 'c' in o;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the built-in filter function.

**Using Lambda:**

```
var x = [ {"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":3, "c":1}, {"a":9, "b":2}, {"a":7, "b":2}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":6}];

var filteredX = x.filter(obj => obj.c !== void 0);

console.log(filteredX);
```

**Normal function syntax:**

```
var x = [ {"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3, "b":3, "c":1}, {"a":9, "b":2}, {"a":7, "b":2}, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":6}];

var filteredX = x.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.c !== void 0;
});

console.log(filteredX);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get first the common keys and create new objetcs based on the keys.

```js
var array = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 3, c: 1 }, { a: 9, b: 2 }, { a: 7, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 6 }],
    common = array.reduce(function (r, o, i) {
        var keys = Object.keys(o);
        return i ? r.filter(function (k) { return keys.indexOf(k) + 1; }) : keys;
    }, []),
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        common.forEach(function (k) {
            o[k] = a[k];
        });
        return o;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filter method of javascript :

```
Var newArray= array.filter(function(elem, i, array).   {
    return element.hasOwnProperty("c");
}
```

);